# Understanding one example in the Eloquent JS 3th edition

Tags: javascript, recursion

If I put `return (n-1)*n` that is 8-1=7*8=56

But if I put like in the book example `return factorial(n-1)*n` then it returns 40320.

How does the calculation/math works? It returns a function, it return itself - right?
But I don't know how this works. How does it get to the number 40320?

```js
const factorial = function(n) {
  if (n === 0) {
    return 1
  } else {
    return factorial(n - 1) * n
  }
}

console.log(factorial(8))
```

Comment: `It returns a function` No, it *evaluates* the function call (which resolves to a number), and returns that number

Comment: `8! = 40320`, 8! = factorial(8). 8! = 8 * 7! = 8 * 7 * 6! = 8 * 7 * 6 * 5! = etc... = 40320

Comment: Assume `factorial(7)` returns 5040. Then `factorial(7) * 8` returns 40320. OK? Why does `factorial(7)` return 5040? Because `factorial(6)` is 720, and `720 * 7` is 5040. Finally, `factorial(0)` is 1, nothing else to look up. This is called ["recursion"](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=recursion), which means evaluating things recursively. :P

Comment: Hi Ivano! Welcome to StackOverflow!. [Here is an excellent article](https://medium.com/backticks-tildes/recursion-for-beginners-bd0d81ea6582) on Recursion. I advice that you read it to understand how recursion work

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can calculate the factorial of any natural number (`n`) by doing:

```
n! = n * n-1 * n-2 * n-3 * ... * 1
```

Eg:

```
4! = 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 = 24
```

This can be simplified to:

```
n! = n * (n-1)!
```

Eg:

```
4! = 4 * (4-1)! = 4 * 3!

3! = 3 * (3-1)! = 3 * 2!

2! = 2 * (2-1)! = 2 * 1!

1! = 1 * (1-1)! = 1 * 0!

0! = 1
```

So solving this, we can now work back up our equations:

```
0! = 1

1! = 1 * 0! = 1 * (1) = 1 // <--- subbing in as we now know the result of 0! to be 1

2! = 2 * 1! = 2  * (1) = 2

3! = 3 * 2! = 3 * (2) = 6

4! = 4 * 3! = 4 * (6) = 24
```

When we do this with code, we can use recursion. This means we call a function within itself. Taking the above example we can do this using a function called `fact()` instead of using the `!` notation:

```
fact(4) = 4 * fact(4-1) = 4 * fact(3) // same as: 4! = 4 * (4-1)! = 4 * 3!
```

So after running `fact(4)`, we see that we are returning / trying to calculate the result of `4 * fact(3)`. But we don't know what `fact(3)` is yet, so we need to calculate it:

```
fact(3) = 3 * fact(3-1) = 3 * fact(2)
```

Here we are trying to calculate `3 * fact(2)`, but we don't know what `fact(2)` is yet, so we need to work it out:

```
fact(2) = 2 * fact(2-1) = 2 * fact(1)
```

Again, we need to work out what `fact(1)` is:

```
fact(1) = 1 * fact(1-1) = 1 * fact(0)
```

Lastly, we need to work out what `fact(0)` is:

```
fact(0) = 1
```

Here we get `fact(0)` is equal to 1. Notice how `fact(0)` returns a value which doesn't have a reference to another `fact` call. This means that we have reached our *base case* (defined in your `if(n===0)`) and can now calculate/traverse our previous equations we didn't know how to answer.
So going back up to `fact(1)` we now replace the call to `fact(0)` with `1`

```
fact(1) = 1 * fact(0) 1 = 1
```

Now we know what `fact(1)` is, we can now calculate `fact(2)`:

```
fact(2) = 2 * fact(1) 1 = 2
```

Now we know what `fact(2)` is, we can calculate `fact(3)`:

```
fact(3) = 3 * fact(2) 2 = 6
```

Lastly, we can calculate `fact(4)`:

```
fact(4) = 4 * fact(3) 6 = 24
```

So, using this, we get `fact(4) = 24`

This is the basis of how this recursive function works.

So if you use `return (n-1)*n` at the end of your function instead of `return fact(n-1) * n` you are simply just doing one return, and not calling your function again to calculate the factorial of `n-1`.

Answer (score 0):

It returns `factorial(n-1)*n` instead of `(n-1)*n`, hence the calculation would not be just 8*7 = 56. Instead, since it is returning a call to itself, the final calculation would be 8*7*6*5*4*3*2*1 = 40320.

This is called a [recursive function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)). When you called factorial(8), it will return `factorial(7)*8`, which called `factorial(7)` before returning. `factorial(7)` returns `factorial(6)*7`, which called `factorial(6)` before returning. This goes all the way until `factorial(2)` returns `factorial(1)*1`, which called `factorial(1)` that returns `1`.

Then `factorial(2)` returns `factorial(1)*2` = 1*2 = 2, `factorial(3)` returns `factorial(2)*3` = 2*3 = 6, `factorial(4)` returns `factorial(3)*4` = 6*24 = 24, and so on. Lastly, `factorial(8)` returns `factorial(7)*8` = 5040*8 = 40320